# Flutter reading from JSON if value matches

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a json of customers:

**customer.json**

```
[
  {
    "name": "Customer 1",
    "id": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Customer 2",
    "id": "2"
  },
  {
    "name": "Customer 3",
    "id": "3"
  }
]
```

This is the dart file using this json data:

**customerslist.dart**

**Future Method**

```
Future<String> loadCustomers() async{
  var res = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull(url),
      headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
  return res.body;
}
```

**Widget**

```
widgets.add(new FutureBuilder(
              future: loadCustomers(),
              builder: (context, snapshot){
                if(snapshot.hasData){

                  //get snapshot data from JSON tree
                  var jsondecode = json.decode(snapshot.data);

                  return new ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: jsondecode.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index){
                        String name = jsondecode[index]["name"];
                        String id = jsondecode[index]["id"];

                        if(name == "Customer 2"){
                          return new Column(
                            children: <Widget>[

                              new ListTile(
                                title: new Text("Name"),
                                trailing: new Text(name),
                              ),
                              new ListTile(
                                title: new Text("ID"),
                                trailing: new Text(id),
                              )
                            ],
                          );
                        }
                      });
                }else{
                  return new Center(
                    child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
              }));
```

What I am trying to do is bringing out the values if the name matches as you can see from `if(name == "Customer 2")`.

But the problem I am having is:

When i change the if statement to `if(name == "Customer 1")`, the output is as you would expect:

[image: First output]

But if i were to change it to `if(name == "Customer 2")`, the output turns out blank as such:

[image: Second output]

Could someone explain why is it turning out like this or is there another method I could go about doing to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because `Column` widget is taking full height. You could try using the minimum height for your column and add **else condition**.

```
                            if(name == "Customer 2"){
                      return new Column(
                        children: <Widget>[

                          new ListTile(
                            title: new Text("Name"),
                            trailing: new Text(name),
                          ),
                          new ListTile(
                            title: new Text("ID"),
                            trailing: new Text(id),
                          )
                        ],
                      );
                    } else {
                    return new Container();
                    }
```

When you use 'Customer 1' it works fine because your first element is 'Customer 1' , probably you have an error on your console because for other items there are no returning widgets.

In the case of 'Customer 2' the first item is not returned, so check your console log.

`itemBuilder` expects you return a widget for all the cases.

Comment: Thats not it. If i were to check using print statement, if(name == "Customer 2") will still print out blank. I might be doing something wrong with my if statement.

Comment: Surprisingly it works. Could you perhaps explain why does it work when the new Container is added to the else statement?

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll be sure to remember to put widgets for all cases in itemBuilder.

Comment: no problem :) , don't forget to mark the answer as solved and keep Fluttering!!

Answer (score 1):

You just convert the var string to list

```
var jsondecode = json.decode(snapshot.data);

List list = jsondecode;
 String name = list[index]["name"];
                    String id = list[index]["id"];
```

then pass the list to get the index may be this will work bocasue the var type may be get the first json string only

```
enter code here
```